# Eclipse color theme php syntax-highlighting wrong in juno 4.2?

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting, eclipse-pdt

Eclipse 4.2(juno), w/PDT
Installed eclipse color theme plug in, selected "Notepad++ like", clicked apply and ok. But it is giving me the Java syntax colors in my php editor. It seems not to be recognizing php or not giving me php syntax colors. My file associations are working as they all load correctly into the php editor. Am I missing something dumb? I don't want to have to change all the colors by hand, but I can't stand having single and double line comments 2 different colors, aargh! 
Please help,
frank